# Angular and JWT roles disappearance when refresh page

Tags: angular, typescript, jwt

I'm coding a CRUD Application with an authentication part so i manage the directions between pages using roles of JWT, so when the user get logged to the application he will just see the links related to his role in the menu.

**AuthenticationService.ts**

```
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {JwtHelper} from 'angular2-jwt';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {

  private host:string="http://localhost:8080";
  private jwtToken:string=null;
  private roles:Array<any>=[];
  private tk:any;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient){

  }
  login(user){
    return this.http.post(this.host+"/login",user, {observe:'response'});
  }

  logout(){
    this.jwtToken=null;
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  saveToken(jwt:string){
    this.jwtToken=jwt;
    localStorage.setItem('token',jwt);
    let jwtHelper=new JwtHelper();
    this.roles=jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwtToken).roles;
  }

  loadToken(){
    return this.jwtToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
  }

  isAdmin(){
    for(let r of this.roles) {
      console.log("********************************"+r);
      if(r.authority=='ADMIN') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  isDeveloper(){
    for(let r of this.roles) {
      console.log("********************************"+r);
      if(r.authority=='DEVELOPER') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
  isCommercial(){
    for(let r of this.roles) {
      console.log("********************************"+r);
      if(r.authority=='COMMERCIAL') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  isOnline(){
    this.jwtToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (this.jwtToken != null) return true;
    return false;
  }
  isOffline(){
    this.jwtToken=localStorage.getItem('token');
    if (this.jwtToken == null) return true;
    return false;
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <!-- partial -->
  <div [ngClass]="{'container-fluid page-body-wrapper':authenticationService.isOnline()}">
    <!-- partial:partials/_sidebar.html -->
    <nav *ngIf="authenticationService.isOnline()" class="sidebar sidebar-offcanvas" id="sidebar">
      <ul class="nav">
        <li class="nav-item nav-profile">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link">
            <div class="nav-profile-image">
              <img src="assets/images/faces/face1.jpg" alt="profile">
              <span class="login-status online"></span> <!--change to offline or busy as needed-->
            </div>
            <div class="nav-profile-text d-flex flex-column">
              <span class="font-weight-bold mb-2">David Grey. H</span>
              <span class="text-secondary text-small">Project Manager</span>
            </div>
            <i class="mdi mdi-bookmark-check text-success nav-profile-badge"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/tasks">
            <span class="menu-title">Dashboard</span>
            <i class="mdi mdi-home menu-icon"></i>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="authenticationService.isAdmin()" class="nav-item">
          <div class="dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="OnClik3()" data-target="#myNavbar3">
              <span class="menu-title">Admin Area</span>
              <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
              <i class="mdi mdi-worker"></i>
            </a>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" [ngClass]="{'show': buttontoggled3}" id="myNavbar3">
              <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" routerLink="/roles">Roles</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" routerLink="/users">Users</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">XXX API</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li *ngIf="authenticationService.isAdmin() || authenticationService.isCommercial()" class="nav-item">
        <div class="dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="OnClik1()" data-target="#myNavbar1">
            <span class="menu-title">Network</span>
            <i class="menu-arrow"></i>
            <i class="mdi mdi-google-circles-extended"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " [ngClass]="{'show': buttontoggled1}" id="myNavbar1">
            <ul class="nav flex-column sub-menu">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" routerLink="/companies">Companies</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" routerLink="/contacts">Contacts</a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Whatsapp API</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
```

The problem is that when the user is logged the menu is fine but when he refresh the page or click previous or next page, the links in the menu with the conditions above disappear but the user still logged. 
How can i solve this problem? any suggestions please ?

Comment: Looks like when you load the token, you will need to load the roles as well (just like you do in `saveToken`)

Comment: @user184994 thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like @user184994 said i need to load the roles like this :

```
isAdmin(){
    let jwtHelper=new JwtHelper();
    this.roles=jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwtToken).roles;
    for(let r of this.roles) {
      console.log("********************************"+r);
      if(r.authority=='ADMIN') return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
```

Comment: It may be better to only do `this.roles=jwtHelper.decodeToken(this.jwtToken).roles;` once, inside the `loadToken` function, otherwise you will be decoding the token every time you want to check if they're an admin,  which is unnecessary overhead